# subset logic, skipping every other element

Tags: java

Given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of the ints, such that the group sums to the given target with this additional constraint: If a value in the array is chosen to be in the group, the value immediately following it in the array must not be chosen. (No loops needed.)

groupNoAdj(0, [2, 5, 10, 4], 12) → true

groupNoAdj(0, [2, 5, 10, 4], 14) → false

groupNoAdj(0, [2, 5, 10, 4], 7) → false

I was wondering if there was anything left to add, not quite sure where the mistake is:

```
public boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
    if (start == nums.length) {return (target == 0);}

    if (groupNoAdj(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])){
    return true;
  }

    if (groupNoAdj(start + 1, nums, target)){
      return (groupNoAdj(start + 1, nums, target));
    } 

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is modification of your code:

```
public boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] nums, int target) {

        if (start >= nums.length) {return (target == 0);}  //neded to change to '>=' because start can go over length of array 

//in your code you return true when the two following numbers from array are chosen, which is contrary to the requirement of the task 
        if (groupNoAdj(start + 2, nums, target - nums[start])){ 
            return true;
        }

        if (groupNoAdj(start + 1, nums, target)){
            return true;
        } 

        return false;
    }
```

here is brand new code, which for example for input (array = [1,2,3,4,5] and target 99) call function groupNoAdj recursively only 12 times instead of 25.

```
    public boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
        if(target - nums[start] == 0) // there is no need let 'start' be greater than the lenghth of nums' array 
            return true;

  //doing what in the previous code but I am not letting to call function with start greater than the length of nums' array
        if (!(start + 2 >= nums.length) && groupNoAdj(start + 2, nums, target - nums[start])){
            return true;
        } 

        if (!(start + 1 == nums.length) && groupNoAdj(start + 1, nums, target)){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The logic behind this recursion: I am checking all possible sums(I assume that one number is also the sum) from the list of array except cases where two numbers are 'neighbour' to each other.
If you have any questions about this code then ask.
The is no recipe for solving this problem, you must just simple practice, practice and practice more and you will see how to attack the problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question